# flutter developer Android and IOS

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

In the windows How can I publish flutter project from android studio to appstore for apple
I want to methods to publish my app to appstore without mac OS

Comment: You could create the environment in windows for running Xcode but that is not motivated to do. You need macOS for it.

Answer (score 0):

The anwer is you "You can't." You need a MacOS to generate the app installer to be put on App Store.

Answer (score 0):

To develop Flutter apps for iOS, you need a Mac with Xcode installed

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/macos